Is it a correct rendering of Acts 1,24 when the New World Translation puts in „Jehovah“ instead of Lord?
This specific question as to Acts 1,24 has not yet been treated in this forum. We have general discussions on the usage of Jehovah in the NT but not with a primary focus on this verse. I don’t see a connection between the question to which name Jesus is referring to in Matthew 6,9 and the implementation of Jehovah in Acts 1,24. The NWT inserts Jehovah whenever we have a direct citation of a verse of the OT. In Acts 1,24 we don’t have a citation of an OT verse. My question should challenge supporters of the NWT present in this forum. I voluntarily correct myself if there are any scriptural reasons for translating against the greek original. —- References to Matthew aren’t helpful in interpreting the usage of Lord kyrios by his disciples after the ascension of Jesus.

In the particular instance of Acts 1:24, I agree that the prayer addressed to "Lord" is the same Jehovah of the OT.  However, as general principle, I object to the NWT practice of substituting "Jehovah" for "Lord" in various places for the following reasons:

The distinction between "Lord" and "Jehovah" is absent from the Greek text and thus, it is unbiblical!
Making such a distinction in various places makes the translators decide which is which - and many are quite controversial and unsubstantiated
While there are many places where the substitution of "Jehovah" for "Lord" might be justified on the basis of an OT quotation (eg, see Translation of Matt 22:44, "The Lord said to my Lord ... " ) Acts 1:24 is not such.
And that is the point - the inspired NT writers (despite some claims to the contrary, the translators of the NWT were not inspired!) these NT writers uniformly chose to render YHWH in the OT as "Lord" in the NT.
The final problem is the most flagrant.  Even when there is good justification in translation "Lord" as "Jehovah" when quote a Jehovah passage of the OT, the NWT refuse to do so when the reference is to Jesus such as:


Acts 7:59 (quoting Ps 31:4 and Eccl 12:7)
1 Peter 2:3 (quoting Ps 34:8)
Heb 1:10-12 (quoting Ps 102:25-27)
Phil 2:10, 11 (quoting Isa 45:23)

On the last point - I am aghast that some have the effrontery to assume a greater knowledge than the inspired NT writers by effectively correcting the NT text.  I, for one, regard the sacred text of the NT too important to change and do not support any suggestion for such a change.

To begin answering, it is helpful to consult the Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures (KIT), as the Greek text of Westcott & Hort is given alongside the Watchtower Society's English version of it.  I have the 1969 edition of it in front of me and can assure readers here that the Greek text has 'Kyrios' in Acts 1:24, rendered 'Lord' by Westcott & Hort, but in the English version column, that has been changed to 'Jehovah'. A footnote refers to three 'J' translations claimed to support this. They are dated 1599 (Hutter's Polyglott NT); 1661 (Wm. Robertson's revision of that); and 1892 (Franz Delitzsch's translation of the Greek scriptures into Hebrew- one of ten editions).
The whole matter of how the KIT deals with 'Kyrios' in the Greek scriptures has been written about in great detail, and in scholarly manner, in literature that is freely available on-line (though the author died a few years ago). Here is a little about what he says regarding the way the KIT does that.

"There can be no debate that the Greek text of the KIT uses the Greek
word Kyrios 714 times throughout the Christian Greek Scriptures.
This includes all 223 instances in which the New World Translation
renders Kyrios as Jehovah.
On what basis can the divine name be reinstated to the Greek
Scriptures of the New World Translation? There is only one
acceptable justification for this translation choice. Since the
inspired Christian Scriptures is the written record of the original
authors, there would need to be incontrovertible evidence that the
apostles themselves used the Tetragrammaton in their original
writings. Further, this evidence would be admissible only if it could
be textually verified in the most authoritative extant Greek
manuscripts. Speculation regarding possible use cannot be employed
to alter Jehovah's inspired Scriptures.
The New World Translation uses 237 Jehovah references in its
Christian Scriptures. Is the most accurate reproduction of the
inspired Word of God from reliable Greek manuscripts represented in
the KIT? Or is the most accurate reproduction of God's Word to be
found in Hebrew translations completed in the 14th century and later?
[Footnote refers to his evaluation of these, including the three I mention
in my opening paragraph, in chapter 2 of his book The New World
Translation and Hebrew Versions. Those 'J' references are fairly
demolished but there's no room here to detail that.]
Inspiration has been redefined when the best manuscript evidence for
the Greek Scriptures is replaced with the wording of Hebrew
translations. This is particularly true when these Hebrew versions
were translated from the exact Greek texts that do not contain the
Tetragrammaton. The inspiration of the Greek Scriptures has been
denied in these 237 instances." Jehovah in the New Testament booklet,
pp. 6-7, published in 2001 with no copyright and for free distribution.
http://www.tetragrammaton.org

And one of those instances is Acts 1:24, where the accepted Greek text does not have the Tetragrammaton.
The author says in another booklet:

"The translator cannot become a commentator, explaining what he (the
commentator) believes the Scripture writer intended to say.
This does not ignore the fact that a translator must often make
subjective choices when translating a word or a phrase from Greek into
English. In many instances, that decision will involve the personal
opinion of the translator regarding word meanings according to the
context. Kyrios was a common secular word in the Greek language
of Jesus' day. It is appropriately translated in the NWT as Sir [Mark
7:28], owner [Matthew 21:40], master [Matthew 25:26], a protocol form
of address for an emperor [Acts 25:26], and slave master [Ephesians
6:5]. However, this does not give the translator the privilege of
substituting one known word for another with an entirely different
meaning as would be the case in substituting the divine name for
Lord." The Divine Name in the New World Translation booklet, p.68, details as above.

That last sentence sums up in a nutshell the answer to the question, which is that Acts 1:24 in the NWT has been incorrectly rendered as 'Jehovah', given that the Greek text does not have the Tetragrammaton in it, but Kyrios.

First audience perspective - who was speaking in Acts 1:24?  From vs. 15, Peter was speaking to the other disciples.  Was Peter speaking to them in Greek?  Or was Peter, as a Galilean addressing the other Galilean & Judean disciples speaking in either the northern Aramaic dialect or the Hebrew language?  Just b/c the NT scriptures were recorded in Koine Greek does not mean the actual name of God was spoken in Koine Greek as "Kyrios".

@Gina   At that time, the actual name of God was not spoken. Full stop.

Anne, you are right.  They wouldn't have spoken the name.  Neither would they have said Kyrios.  The written record is an accommodation to the baseless Jewish fear to write or speak His name, & so is a substitution for God's name, YHVH.  From the OT, Strong's H3068, YHVH, phonetic Yehowah. https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3068.htm  The intent of the NWT was based on the context & is proper to use the name of God in the translation.

The Study Note for Act 1:24 refers to Appendix C of The New World Translation (Study Edition). Specifically, Appendix C3 "Verses Where the Divine Name Does Not Appear as Part of Direct or Indirect Quotations in the Book of Acts" gives the reason for the use of Jehovah in this verse:

REASON(S): Available Greek manuscripts use the term “Lord” (Kyʹri·os) here, but there are good reasons for using the divine name in the main text. In the Christian Greek Scriptures,  Kyʹri·os  can refer to Jehovah God or to Jesus Christ, depending on the context. The Hebrew Scriptures frequently identify Jehovah God as the one with the ability to read hearts. (Deuteronomy 8:2; 1 Samuel 16:7; 1 Kings 8:39; 1 Chronicles 28:9; Psalm 44:21; Jeremiah 11:20; 17:10) It would have been natural in this context, then, for those Hebrew-speaking Jews to use the divine name when praying to God. The Greek word  kar·di·o·gnoʹstes  (lit., “knower of hearts”) occurs only here and at  Acts 15:8, where it clearly refers to God. Although existing Greek manuscripts of Acts use the word  Kyʹri·os  (Lord) here, the context and the Hebrew Scripture background, as well as the ambiguity of the term  Kyʹri·os,  provide good reasons for using the divine name in the main text.
SUPPORT:

The Anchor Yale Bible,  by Joseph A. Fitzmyer, 1998, (Vol. 31) says of  Acts 1:24:  “Lord, you know the hearts of all.  God is addressed by the Christian community as  Kyrie  [a form of  Kyʹri·os], a title used by Luke elsewhere for Yahweh of the OT [Old Testament] (Luke 1:16, 32, 68; 4:8, 12; 10:27; 19:38; 20:37, 44; Acts 2:39; 3:22; 5:9).” With regard to the expression “know the hearts,” this reference work goes on to acknowledge that “it is a title for God appearing only in Christian writings.”

The reference work  Exegetical Dictionary of the New Testament,  1991, (Vol. 2, pp. 329-330) lists  Acts 1:24  as a verse where  Kyʹri·os  is “used of Yahweh.”

The Companion Bible,  with notes by E. W. Bullinger, 1999 printing, in Appendix 98, “Divine Names and Titles in New Testament,” lists  Acts 1:24  on page 143, under the heading “LORD . . . Used of Jehovah.”

The  Aramaic English New Testament  (Third Edition), by Andrew Gabriel Roth, 2008, says in this verse: “You Master YHWH know that which is in the hearts of all.” The footnote on this verse says: “The early talmidim called on the Name of YHWH in prayer; however, this was obscured when generic Greek terms were implemented to replace the Personal and Covenant Name of YHWH. This was done in violation of the Commandments: Do not add to, nor take away from the Word D’varim/Deut. 4:2  and do not take the Name of YHWH in vain, Sh’mot  [Ex] 20:7.”


SUPPORTING REFERENCES: J7, 8, 10, 17, 22, 23, 29, 30, 32, 36, 44, 65, 66, 93, 96, 100, 106, 115, 125, 132, 138, 139, 145-147, 160, 164, 201, 310, 323, 324

For a list of the J references, see Appendix C4 "Translations and Reference Works Supporting the Use of the Divine Name in the “New Testament”".

I wondered if you might have something further to say, when I made reference to an answer of yours in a link that I referenced in my own answer here. I don't have the NWT (study edition), only the 1984 regular edition and the 1985 KIT, along with vol's 1 & 2 of Insight on the Scriptures, so thank you for this. You have my vote again now for sure.

@OldeEnglish Everyone has access to the official site, jw.org, which has a Library section. This includes the the NWT (Study Edition), 1984 NWT, 1985 KIT, KJV, ASV, BLE along with other many of our other publications. The Watchtower Online Library has all those publications and others that go back even further than what is available at jw.org.

Yeah, I should have gone there, normally I do. I went to the back of Insight on the Scriptures, Vol 2 but nothing was said about this verse, so I guess I thought it would not be referenced elsewhere. My bad.

@RevelationLad The use of Ps 44:21 is in reference to God/Jehovah as the reader of hearts. Yes, we are to "ask the Father in [Jesus'] name" (John 15:16) but we are still praying to Jehovah God. As to your assumption, that you will need to conclude yourself.

Yes, Jehovah is the correct use at Acts 1:24 as in most other instances where the word "Lord" is inserted.  The substitution of "Lord" in place of God's name became a common practice because the correct spelling of Tetragrammaton YHVH was confused from Masoretic practice of inserting vowel markers from Adonai (Lord) and Elohim.  But, the correct spelling of God's name as "Jehovah" is of long standing.

The three vowel sounds in the pointing used by the Massoretes led eventually to the sound Jehovah in Latin and then English. The first to use this form in English translation (as Iehouah) was William Tyndale (1530*). Some writers still erroneously credit him with inventing this spelling.7 Tyndale used Iehouah at Exodus 6 v. 3 and LORD elsewhere. The earliest English version to regularly use Jehovah where the TG occurs appears to be that of Henry Ainsworth (1622*). This writer has the 1639 folio of Ainsworth’s Annotations upon the five books of Moses and the books of Psalms, printed by M. Parsons for John Bellamie, and Jehovah (or Iehovah) is used throughout. According to Herbert, Ainsworth’s Psalms first appeared in 1612, and the Pentateuch from 1616. In his annotation on Genesis 2 v. 4, Ainsworth commented: “Iehovah - this is Gods proper name.


It commeth of Havah, he was, and by the firft letter I. it fignifieth, he will be, and by the fecond Ho, it fignifieth, he is…Paft, prefent and to come are comprehended in this proper name as is knowne unto all…It implieth alfo, that God hath his being or exiftence of himselfe before the world was, that he giveth being unto all things…that he giveth being to his word effecting whatfoever he fpeaketh.” (Although outside the scope of this article it should be noted that the form Jehova was previously used extensively in the Latin Bible of Tremellio and Junio first published in four parts over 1575-79.) Source: Handling the Tetragrammaton

The preface of many of the English translations explain the substitution of "Lord" for Jehovah.  From the preface of the American Standard Bible:

THE PROPER NAME OF GOD IN THE OLD TESTAMENT: In the Scriptures, the name of God is most significant and understandably so. It is inconceivable to think of spiritual matters without a proper designation for the Supreme Deity. Thus the most common name for the Deity is God, a translation of the original Elohim. One of the titles for God is Lord, a translation of Adonai. There is yet another name which is particularly assigned to God as His special or proper name, that is, the four letters YHWH (Exodus 3:14 and Isaiah 42:8). This name has not been pronounced by the Jews because of reverence for the great sacredness of the divine name. Therefore, it has been consistently translated LORD. The only exception to this translation of YHWH is when it occurs in immediate proximity to the word Lord, that is, Adonai. In that case it is regularly translated GOD in order to avoid confusion. It is known that for many years YHWH has been transliterated as Yahweh, however no complete certainty attaches to this pronunciation. Source: PrefaceAMStd

The original spelling in the Latin was "Iehovah."  The "J" was invented for the English language some time in the 14th century, and became more widely used in the 17th century AD.  The original English translations used the "I" and not the "J" spelling.
God's name had to be spelled phonetically in the Greek and Latin translations as the Hebrew letters could not be used.  The Tetragrammaton YHVH - there was no "W" in the ancient Hebrew - became "Iehovah" in the Greek as the letter "I" with a vowel became the "y" sound.  Ex. "ia" sounded like "yah," and "ie," sounded like "yeh," and "Io" sound like "yoh."  As the letter "i" was already a different sound in both Greek and Latin as a long "eeee" sound, the letter "j" was invented with hook at the bottom of the "i" to become the "y" sound for "yah" or "yeh."
Originally, the name James was spelled as "Iames."  The names beginning with "J" in our English translations of the Hebrew scriptures were spoken with a Y sound.  So, Jacob sounded like "Yacov," and Jeremiah sounded like "Yeremiah," and Jerusalem was "Yerus(h)alayim."  We still hear the "Y" in the German Johann, and Jesu.
The original pronunciation of Jehovah as Iehovah was Yahowah, not Yaweh.  The latter use is of recent invention and is not correct.  Josephus stated that the sacred name was four vowel sounds. (Source: Wars Bk 5, Chap 5, para 7) When we look at the evidences those four vowel sounds were "eee yah ooo wah."
The correct pronunciation of Jehovah (Iehova) is Yah ooo wah.  The first syllable begins by forming a long "eee." Say it slow and you will hear it - eee yah ooo wah.
God's name is not said as "yah waaay."  That is confusion of the Latin "e" vowel which is a long "aaa" sound.
More evidences presented at my post The Name of God.

The Masoretes developed their text after 600-1000 AD. Hard to understand how their work impacted Greek and Latin manuscripts written before.

Is it a correct rendering of Acts 1:24 when the New World Translation puts in "Jehovah" instead of Lord?
First of all: Which divinity - or if of the Trinitarian ilk - Which spiritual personage of the so called triune God, is actually being talked about here?? Answer: The Almighty, Himself. Although to be fair if one goes to Biblehub.com, the old sages are split on whether we are talking The Almighty, or whether we are talking of Jesus. Ellicott, although unsure, points to the analogy in Acts 4:29, where the Father is entreated to work signs and wonders, "Through His holy servant Jesus". Also, the Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges points to Proverbs 16:33 and Acts 15:8, as proof that the Almighty, Himself is to be seen as the final authority on such matters regarding - knowing the hearts of all men. If then we are indeed talking of The Almighty, then the NWT's usage of Jehovah can indeed be explained by way of qualification.
For further discussions on the NWT's use of Jehovah, some 237 times, in the NT, one can check out the following Q's, to which I and others gave our views, not to mention comments, where we tackle the problem of extant MSS and non-extant MSS and the writings of prominent 1st and 2nd Century Christian theologians/translators/historians: How is the New World Translation's usage of "Jehovah" controversial? Besides my answer here, I would recommend viewing Trig's and Vahppus's answers and particularly my comments to Anne. Why is YHWH, the name of the God, replaced by a title, "the LORD", why is the article "the" used? The 1st of thousands of references, Gen 2:4 Besides my answer here, I would without any reservation recommend Alex's answer (the top answer) and Agarza's answer.
Finally, you could also take note of the following, also taken again from the Watchtower's extraordinary pamphlet entitled "The Divine Name That Will Endure Forever":-

How does Jehovah view those who remove His name from the Bible? If you were an author, how would you feel about someone who went to great lengths to remove your name from the book you authored? Translators who object to the name, doing so on account of problems of pronunciation or because of Jewish tradition, might be compared to those who Jesus said "strain out the gnat but gulp down the camel!" (Matthew 23:24) They stumble over these smaller problems but end up creating a major problem - by removing the name of the greatest personage in the universe from the book that He inspired.


The apostles prayed to Jesus. He was the one who appointed them and now one was missing. So where’s the problem? Why be polemic about trinity? Why should Jesus be part of a trinity? I know a lot of unitarians who pray to Jesus. Besides the JW who pray to the Governing Body.

I downvote the comment for the following reasons: 1) we speak about the question if the apostles prayed to Jesus as their Lord in Acts 1,24 which has nothing to do with the trinity. (2) Jesus himself knew the hearts of men like his father: Matthew 9,4; Mark 2,8; Luke 5,22; (3) Jesus as the head of the church appointed the apostles and is in Ephesians 4,11 the one who appointed prophets etc in the church (4) Jesus appointed the apostle Paul directly and Paul spoke to him.


the comment is not precise as the citation of the JW brochure refers to the 6800 places where YHWH has been replaced by Lord and there the brochure has a point indeed ; here we speak about the NT and additionally about a verse where we don’t have an OT citation. How does the father feel about persons who put all their energy into downsizing his son who died for mankind contrary to John 5,23. Those who don’t have the son don’t have the father. John 17,11 - the name of the father has been given to the son.


@GuidoGaudlitz - Here's hoping we can continue in a civil manner here. Well, who the apostles prayed to is questionable, as pointed out by me and now by Agarza also. If we knew for sure who the apostles prayed to and that it was Jesus, then there would indeed be a problem. I was just trying to be ambivalent, nothing more, when I mentioned the Trinity in my opening sentence. Jesus did indeed know the hearts of men, just like his father. I cannot dispute your points 3 & 4 but hardly relevant here. By the way, you keep saying comment but I think you mean answer... tbc...

@GuidoGaudlitz -ctd- 5) It's good that you don't have a problem with the NWT with regard to the OT. We do now speak about the NT and additionally about a verse where we don't have an OT citation, but again irrelevant here. The Son is answerable to the Father, as he should be. That isn't to say that by acknowledging this, the Son is being downsized. We honor the Son by: 1) going  through him to get to the Father, and 2) by acknowledging that Jesus died for our sins to ensure our salvation. That isn't being contrary to John 5:23. As for John 17:11 the Father's name is already within the Son's.

@GuidoGaudlitz - One last thing the JW's do indeed have a Governing Body, who advise and keep order,  but the JW's do not pray to them. They pray to God, through the mediator Jesus Christ. All prayers are ultimately to God. Finally, I find your downvote unwaranted. Even though I disagree with you I have never downvoted you.

Olde English - up voted, & tho we disagree on some things, we do agree on others.  Substitutions, transliterations, and mis-translations have still entered into the translations.  But, the Holy Spirit has kept the essential doctrinal matters in hand.  It seems Guido expects the Holy Spirit to control all aspects of man kind.

@Gina - Well, thank you. I'm not so sure that I was expecting that reciprocation, nevertheless much appreciated. I can also agree that God's spirit may indeed have kept the essential doctrinal matters in hand, but of course you of all people, here on BHSE, know that I don't believe in the personage of the said spirit but we don't need to go into that here.
